# how to exclude multiple zip code from adword campaign via script?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am facing issue in google AdWords.
I want to exclude zip code from all campaign via a script, script applied on account for all campaign

```
    function main() {
  excludeLocationTarget();
}
function excludeLocationTarget() {
  var campaignIterator = AdsApp.campaigns()
      .withCondition('Name = "US-WooCommerce"')
      .get();
  if (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
    var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
    // Exclude Tennessee, United States (location id = 21175) See
    // https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting
    // for list of all supported geo codes.
    // You could pass either the location code, or a TargetedLocation or
    // ExcludedLocation object from an existing campaign.
    var tennessee_id =['21175','21176'];
    for(val in tennessee_id){
      Logger.log(tennessee_id[val]);
      campaign.excludeLocation(tennessee_id[val]);
    }

  }
}
```

7/31/2019 11:45:44 PM   21175
7/31/2019 11:45:44 PM   Invalid argument: id. Should be of type: number (file Code.gs, line 19)

Answer (score 0):

`excludeLocation` method expects an integer argument and you're using string. that's why `excludeLocation` fails.
try

```
var tennessee_id =[21175,21176]; // numerical values instead of strings
    for(val in tennessee_id){
      Logger.log(tennessee_id[val]);
      campaign.excludeLocation(tennessee_id[val]);
    }
```

or `campaign.excludeLocation(parseInt(tennessee_id[val]));`